# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "por un tubo"?

Tags: modismos, expresiones

Desde 2001, el DRAE recoge varias acepciones bastante simpáticas para la expresión *[por un tubo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=are90sf)*:

1. Una usada en algunos países de América Latina, que significa "rápidamente y con facilidad".

> El paquete que pedí ha llegado como por un tubo.

2. Otra al parecer más usada en España (no estoy seguro de esto), que significa "en gran cantidad".

> Mi primo está ganando dinero por un tubo.
>
> No me gusta esta playa, tiene piedras por un tubo.

Veo que el significado primero tiene muchísima más lógica, dado que directamente recuerda al sistema de envío de objetos a través de contenedores cilíndricos que viajan por tubos, usados en muchas empresas y comercios, y que permiten enviar dichos objetos con mucha celeridad. En cambio, el segundo es el que se me hace un poco más raro. ¿En qué momento "por un tubo" pasó a significar "en gran cantidad"? ¿Cómo se originó este significado? Y como pregunta aparte, ¿es conocida esta acepción fuera de España?

Comment: Saberlo, no lo sé. Tal vez tenga que ver con [esto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foie_gras#Controversia) ([en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foie_gras#Force-feeding_phase)).

Comment: @cdlvcdlv pues posiblemente tengas razón, porque la expresión _por un tubo_ se usa mucho con el verbo comer: _nos han puesto de comer por un tubo_. Puedes expandir tu comentario un poco y convertirlo en respuesta, si quieres.

Comment: Pues en cuanto tenga un rato lo elaboro como respuesta.

Comment: No creo que tenga que ver con la alimentación forzada. La frase la escuchaba de mis abuelos y ellos la usaban desde cuando los animales se criaban libres en la granja. En Colombia la usamos para expresar agilidad o rapidez de la siguiente forma. _Esa correo llegó como por entre un tubo_

Comment: @DGaleano esa acepción la recojo en el enunciado de la pregunta, la cual iba más dirigida al origen de la acepción más empleada en el español europeo, la de "en gran cantidad".

Comment: Eso lo entiendo. Mi punto es que no comparto la respuesta "aceptada".

Comment: @DGaleano entiendo. Según la RAE, las acepciones son modernas y la verdad es que por más que he buscado no he encontrado apenas estos usos figurados en textos escritos, y siempre ha sido en textos recientes. Por supuesto, las respuestas aceptadas pueden variar si alguien ofrece una alternativa mejor.

Comment: Que pena insistir pero parece que no he sido claro. Tu pregunta y todo lo que dices es perfectamente válido, pero mi opinión es que no se debe aceptar **ninguna respuesta** hasta que haya una que cumpla ciertos requisitos como incluir referencias validas, no incluir solo supuestos, etc. Si miras el foro hay muchas preguntas en las cuales ninguna respuesta es completamente buena y por lo tanto no hay ninguna marcada como aceptada. No es obligatorio aceptar una respuesta y no hay un plazo para hacerlo... pero es tu pregunta y puedes aceptar como respuesta la que tu quieras.

Comment: Mi primera búsqueda en google de "por un tubo" retorna [el titulo de una pelicula chilena de 1919](http://www.ccplm.cl/sitio/como-por-un-tubo/) fecha que creo que contradice el origen aceptado de "alimentación forzada".  Además [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=por+un+tubo&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpor%20un%20tubo%3B%2Cc0) muestra un uso más intensivo de "por un tubo" entre 1800 y 1850 que en la actualidad. Just my two cents

Comment: @DGaleano entiendo tus reticencias, en serio. Sí, he aceptado la respuesta sin más sencillamente porque me cuadra. Ten en cuenta que las dos acepciones, la europea y la latinoamericana, son diferentes y pueden tener distinto origen. Yo pregunto por la europea. La película que mencionas se titula "Como por un tubo", que coincide con la expresión latinoamericana tal y como la recoge el DRAE. Y los textos que encuentra el Ngram son todos del tipo "el líquido desciende por un tubo hasta un matraz", es decir, el sentido literal. El uso figurado es mucho más moderno de lo que mencionas.

Comment: @DGaleano en todo caso, coincido contigo en que las respuestas argumentadas y con enlaces y referencias son muchísimo mejores. Quiero que sepas que tengo en cuenta tu opinión y la trataré de aplicar en adelante. Aunque a veces sea un poco relajado en mis decisiones. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es posible que tenga algo que ver con la [alimentación forzada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foie_gras#Controversia) a la que se somete a patos y gansos para producir el fuagrás. Como puede verse en la foto, se lleva a cabo *por un tubo*.

[image]

La alimentación forzosa también es utilizada en seres humanos en huelga de hambre (en este caso, el tubo es una sonda nasogástrica). Como dice [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/carlos-alejo), esta expresión se utiliza mucho con el verbo *comer*. Habría que comparar los primeros usos registrados (yo diría que es bastante moderna) con la fecha aproximada del conocimiento público de esta práctica, que es también reciente.

En todo caso, un tubo es un dispositivo utilizado para trasladar objetos o materiales de un sitio a otro sin (o con la mínima) pérdida de forma que, cuando sale por el extremo de destino, lo más normal es que lo haga de forma abundante e ininterrumpida. En nuestra imaginación tenemos el concepto de que esta es una forma eficiente de producir un gran flujo de algo hacia un lugar: ***por un tubo***.

### Adenda:

Respecto a la validez de esta respuesta.

Ciertamente, es una mera conjetura: nunca he dicho lo contrario. También he añadido que habría que contrastarla con el uso registrado de la expresión. Pero, cuando dije que creía que la expresión era moderna no era solo mi impresión. Antes de realizar la conjetura busqué en el Corpus y todos los usos que encontré o eran literales (aunque reconozco que no termino de enterarme de cómo se usa el dichoso buscador ese) o eran muy modernos. Especialmente, me llamó la atención [una reseña de 1996 sobre un diccionario fraseológico, publicada en "ABC literario"](http://hemeroteca.abc.es/nav/Navigate.exe/hemeroteca/madrid/cultural/1996/09/13/012.html):

> Metáforas felices, hallazgos sintácticos, tropos y elipsis se suceden
>   con su innegable fuerza expresiva. En sus páginas reencontramos
>   expresiones que nos son familiares en el uso o en el recuerdo, no
>   siempre bien entendidas o empleadas por su falta de cristalización
>   normativa pero vigentes en el repertorio del lenguaje popular. Incluso
>   **expresiones modernas, de dudosa continuidad ("por un tubo"**, "patinarle las neuronas", "de mogollón") aparecen recopiladas como
>   testimonio del carácter vivo de la lengua y del genio ancestral de la
>   comunidad hablante.

Esta reseña está firmada por Joaquín Amado, considerado por Víctor Olmos, en su "Historia del ABC", como ["alma del primer libro de estilo del periódico"](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22joaquin+amado%22+%22alma+del+primer+libro+de+estilo+del+periodico%22&oq=%22joaquin+amado%22+%22alma+del+primer+libro+de+estilo+del+periodico%22&gs_l=serp.3...4581.6056.0.6585.9.9.0.0.0.0.433.1205.0j2j2j0j1.5.0....0...1.1.64.serp..5.2.461...30i10.QKQDhfOsF-g). Cuando alguien tan experto en el uso del español como para ser alma de un libro de estilo considera una expresión "de dudosa continuidad" es muy probable que no sea muy antigua. A fecha de hoy, aún no han pasado 20 años de esta reseña, pero parece que la expresión tiene buena salud (no así "de mogollón", que no recuerdo haber oído en mucho tiempo).

Esto no significa que mi conjetura sea correcta y, si aparece un contraejemplo (por ejemplo, un uso anterior, digamos, a 1970), pues mi conjetura es errónea: a seguir buscando. Si nos gusta SE, creo, es porque apreciamos antes la verdad que la diplomacia y distinguimos al creyente de la creencia: mientras que al primero se le reconoce un respeto intrínseco (y por eso nos dirigimos los unos a los otros con respeto), la segunda puede no merecer ninguno. Creo.

El párrafo final de mi respuesta también es conjetura pero expone una explicación más general de por qué el tubo se considera el portador de la abundancia.

Answer (score 3):

Una explicación que me gustó mucho era que la expresión venía de "beber por un tubo" y luego se fue generalizando a otras cosas.
Era costumbre que en los pueblos y ciudades pequeñas cuando se terminaba la construcción del órgano de la iglesia, el párroco invitara a los asistentes a un vino. La cantidad mínima de vino que debía ofrecer era de la capacidad del tubo mayor del órgano recién fabricado. De hecho, en muchos pueblos se sacaba el tubo mayor a la plaza y se llenaba de vino y se servía directamente del tubo.

No sé si es la más certera explicación, pero a mí me ha parecido muy bonita y por eso la comparto.
Nacho

Comment: Así es como lo conozco, también lo he escuchado en un registro coloquial: "Te vay(vas) a ir por un tubo si hacís(haces) eso". Es decir, si el interlocutor acepta el consejo va a poder llevar a cabo la acción sin grandes inconvenientes, fácilmente, con facilidad, con fluidez, con soltura, sin dilación, sin tardanza, sin interrupciones o trabas, en confianza, sin estrechez.

Answer (score 1):

Este refrán tiene que ver con lo recto o prontitud con que se hacen las cosas. Ejemplo un tubo por lo general es recto, de ahí que los demas elementos de la gafeteria plomeria etc haga distinción de los demas elementos. Codo trampa (sifón) de modo que como el tubo lleva su contenido de manera directa por eso la expresión como un tubo de manera directa y expedita.

Answer (score 0):

También es una conjetura, pero para mí, es una expresión vulgar que posiblemente tiene que ver con el tubo de la cañería o el drenaje. Cuando desechas algo por el baño, lo tienes por excremento o por absoluta asquerosidad, jalas la llave y lo mandas por un tubo...

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se] (Es recomendable visitar, si no lo has hecho ya, las secciones de [answer], [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio). Como respuesta no es mala, pero no entiendo la analogía con la "asquerosidad". Tampoco creo que la expresión sea vulgar. El significado de la expresión es "En gran cantidad; Con facilidad o rapidez". Es cierto que al desechar algo por el retrete nos liberamos de ello con rapidez y facilidad, pero no me termina de convencer como origen de una locución que significa "en gran cantidad; con rapidez".

Answer (score 0):

Todo esto es muy interesante. Casualmente, a mis hermanas y a mí nos surgió hoy esta curiosidad, ¿de dónde viene la expresión "por un tubo"?, y buscando información llegué aquí (a StackExchange).

Soy de Puerto Rico, y también recuerdo haber utilizado esta expresión en mi infancia. La usábamos para exagerar, para enviar lejos a alguien que estaba molestando, porque estábamos en desacuerdo con ella, o simplemente con intención de que se fuera y no regresara en un tiempo. A la misma expresión, en ocasiones se le añadía la coletilla “por un tubo y siete llaves”, reafirmando con ello la intencionalidad de que la persona que estaba molestando se fuera bien lejos y no volviera. La premisa ---“7 llaves”--- significaba que antes de regresar, debía abrir primero esas siete llaves.

Así, en función de la intención con que se exprese en la locución, designará una cosa u otra: el tubo de desagüe del inodoro, el tubo de cerveza, el tubo de alimento o sonda, etc.

Todos estamos de acuerdo en que lo que se envíe por el tubo ya no regresará, al menos durante un tiempo, ya que para ello debe abrir primero las 7 llaves.