# ¿Modismo para "drinking from the firehose"?

Tags: traducción, modismos, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

Trabajando en un proyecto para mejorar la formación de nuevos empleados en mi empresa, he recordado que cuando yo empecé en ella, en las dos semanas iniciales que tuve de formación, mucha gente repetía "It is like **drinking (or sipping) from the firehose**".

La traducción directa sería algo así como tratar de beber o dar un sorbito de la manguera de incendios (no una manguera de regar, sino una de camión de bomberos en la que el agua sale con gran caudal y presión).

Esto por supuesto hace referencia a la necesidad de tratar de aprender algo nuevo cuando te están desbordando a información.

> (idiomatic) To be overwhelmed (with work, information, etc.); to be inundated with an uncapped, unfiltered amount
>
> (idiomatic) To take a small amount from an enormous, hard-to-manage quantity
>
> Source: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drink_from_a_firehose)

¿Existe algún modismo o refrán en español que tenga el significado de "drinking/sipping from the firehose"?

Answer (score 3):

Imagino que la expresión hace hincapié en la dificultad de extraer algo de un flujo demasiado grande de información, más que en el hecho de que te estén desbordando con demasiada información.

En un principio he recordado una expresión muy típica y coloquial que se usa cuando recibes algo en grandes cantidades, y que además ya [ha sido tratada aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17351/12637):

> **[por un tubo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=are90sf#DMxWR4E)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. En gran cantidad. *Gana dinero por un tubo.* U. t. c. loc. adj.

Se puede perfectamente decir que estás "recibiendo información por un tubo". Se entiende la sensación de estar desbordado, y se puede inferir de la expresión (aunque no lo diga expresamente) que luego te queda la tarea de aprender y extraer lo más importante.

No sé si habrá alguna expresión que cuadre más exactamente con el original, aunque es bastante probable.

Answer (score 0):

En una situación como la descripta se podrían usar figurativamente varias expresiones, como por ejemplo:

- *meter información a presión*
- *inundar de datos*
- *acribillar con información*
- *bombardear con instrucciones*
- *caer con un millón de tareas*
- *tirar una lluvia de datos*

(Quizá *tirar* sea muy regional, pero es como yo lo diría; otros preferirán *arrojar* o *lanzar*.)

Todas estas expresiones tienen en común que son activas, es decir, se enfoca en que hay un agente que emite una gran cantidad de información obligando a otra a recibirla. Por lo menos yo no consideraría natural una expresión empleando el símil del tubo, pero puede ser una cuestión dialectal. En Argentina decimos *Se me fue la plata como por un tubo* cuando gastamos mucho dinero sin poder evitarlo, pero nunca *Me dieron cosas para aprender como por un tubo* ni nada parecido; el tubo en cuestión parece ser un dispositivo pasivo.

Cabe la posibilidad, también, de emplear el mismo símil que en inglés. Por ejemplo, uno podría decir:

> *Pregunté qué tenía que hacer y **fue como si hubiera abierto una manguera de incendios**.*

Pero como no se trata de una frase hecha, el hablante seguramente sentiría la necesidad de aclarar el símil a continuación.